# .Net Framework application with .Net Remoting in Linux OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-4.8, wine, .net-remoting

Is it Possible to make a .Net Framework Application work in Linux OS ?
We have a pretty huge WPF application which uses .Net Remoting and calls to SQL server.
Converting .NET framework code to .NET core is not a option as it would need lots of efforts.

I am seeing mixed content in the internet on this feasibility by using Wine with ubuntu .And all articles point out to migrate to .net core first .

So , Is it possible to make this .net application work in Linux OS without migrating to .Net core . If its possible , then what are some pointers to consider and where to start with .

Comment: _"Converting .NET framework code to .NET core is not a option as it would need lots of efforts."_ - I can't think of anything you'd actually need to "convert" - let alone rewrite (it's ASP.NET which got people doing that - but a WPF program from 2005 will largely run unmodified on Windows 11 today) - most of the effort involved in transitioning is about updating your project/build files and doing lots of testing...